# IIS 7: HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable. and App pool go to stopped again

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7

I have a win 2008 server and I recently installed google site map the tool stopped my IIS pool app and I start to get HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable

so I went to app pool and restart the stopped apps but they go from start to stopped after few seconds

please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a solution here:
http://code.google.com/p/googlesitemapgenerator/issues/detail?id=98

Answer (score 0):

The path of the Google SiteMap Generator Module was set incorrectly by the installer on Windows Server 2008 running 64bit OS.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Google Sitemap Generator\\IIS7_Module_x64.dll
```

Notice the slashes before the name of the dll file.

To correct the issue do the followings:

- Click your server name in the IIS Manager
- Click ‘Modules’
- Select an entry named like ‘GoogleSiteMapGeneratorModule’ and click ‘Edit’
- Replace the double slash with a single slash in the path field
- You might need to reboot the IIS